# Not scraping correct css despite correct css element in chrome inspect

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

My css element giving the exact same css element in Python selenium when it appears differently as seen in image.

How can I get a the css selectors in the images?  I have tried different css but so far it keeps getting first element and not second.

Css one:
match-pop-market > #options_table > tbody > tr#mtb_row > td:nth-child(1)

Css two:
match-pop-market > #options_table > tbody > tr#mta_row > td:nth-child(1)

Note a and b change.

[image]

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer')



time.sleep(4)



langs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("match-pop-market > #options_table > tbody > tr#mta_row > td:nth-child(1)")
langs_text = []

for lang in langs:
    print(lang.text)
    langs_text.append(lang.text)

print('second css')

langs2 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("match-pop-market > #options_table > tbody > tr#mtb_row > td:nth-child(1)")
langs_text2 = []

for lang in langs:
    print(lang.text)
    langs_text2.append(lang.text)


driver.close()
```

Exact output:

```
Arsenal
Everton
Brighton & Hove Albion
Manchester City
Southampton
Stoke City
Swansea City
West Ham
Burnley
Leicester City
Tottenham Hotspur
AFC Bournemouth
Chelsea
Huddersfield Town
Manchester United
Watford
West Bromwich Albion
Liverpool
Newcastle United
Crystal Palace
AFC Bournemouth
Chelsea
Huddersfield Town
Liverpool
Newcastle United
Watford
Manchester United
Crystal Palace
West Bromwich Albion
```

second css

```
Arsenal
Everton
Brighton & Hove Albion
Manchester City
Southampton
Stoke City
Swansea City
West Ham
Burnley
Leicester City
Tottenham Hotspur
AFC Bournemouth
Chelsea
Huddersfield Town
Manchester United
Watford
West Bromwich Albion
Liverpool
Newcastle United
Crystal Palace
AFC Bournemouth
Chelsea
Huddersfield Town
Liverpool
Newcastle United
Watford
Manchester United
Crystal Palace
West Bromwich Albion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **`css_selector`** and your **`Script`** is perfecto.

Perhaps, in your second `for()` loop you may like to replace `langs` as **`langs2`** within **`for lang in langs:`**. So your code block would look like :

```
print('second css')

langs2 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("match-pop-market > #options_table > tbody > tr#mtb_row > td:nth-child(1)")
langs_text2 = []

for lang in langs2:
    print(lang.text)
    langs_text2.append(lang.text)
```

That wouls